# In html use of style="vertical-align: text-top" doesnt seem to have any effect

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Im trying to get the text following the audio control to be vericaly line with the text in the audio control but its way lower, my use of `style="vertical-align: text-top"` doesnt seem to have any effect

```
<div>
  <span name="fileplay">
    <audio preload="none" controls="controls"><source src="file:/E:/Music/Wav/David%20Guetta/Guetta%20Blaster/01%20-%2007%20-%20Money.wav"></audio>
  </span>
  <span style="vertical-align: text-top">Keep <a href="file:/E:/Music/Wav/David%20Guetta/Guetta%20Blaster/01%20-%2007%20-%20Money.wav">E:\Music\Wav\David Guetta\Guetta Blaster\01 - 07 - Money.wav</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `vertical-align`, the usage is very limited, it aligns inline elements inside its containing line box, note **not** containing box, but line box.

```css
.player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

audio {margin: auto 1.5rem;}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <span name="fileplay">
    <audio preload="none" controls="controls"><source src="Money.wav"></audio>
  </span>
  <span style="vertical-align: text-top">Keep <a href="Money.wav">Money.wav</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks to work but cant get to work when apply to my code. Is it because I have a span between the div and the audio (I need this extra level so I can easily hide the audio control)

Comment: Nah, I have updated the code, you need to make the div display flex, your code did not have the class. And watch out for the file name, it is too long, you may want to hide the part of it.

Comment: thx you are correct silly mistake in my code (the html is generated by java code)

Answer (score 0):

"text-top" aligns the top of the element with the top of the parent element's font, which is often used to align images with the top of letters like "B", "D", "P" etc.

To align a `span`'s top border at the top border of its (non-inline) parent `div`, use `vertical-align: top`

see also here (including some examples): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: vertical;-align:top does do what you say, but not what I want because i want to align with the text in the audio conttrols, i tried vertical-align:middle at that was the same as what i started with with text being too low.

Comment: might need some fine-tuning of the font-size or image sizes... BTW, on the page I linked to there are also examples of individual settings with values in percent and `em`